Property of Haar random state
Let $|\psi\rangle$ be a Haar random state and let $|\psi^{\perp}\rangle$ be any state that is perpendicular to $|\psi\rangle$. Let us define
$$p_x = |\langle x| \psi \rangle|^2,$$
and  $$q_x = |\langle x| \psi^{\perp} \rangle|^2.$$
For any choice of $x \in \{0, 1\}$, I want to compute the quantity
$$
{\mathbb{E}}[p_x q_x],
$$
where the expectation is taken over the choice of the state $|\psi\rangle$. Is this exponentially small?

I know that since $p_x, q_x \geq 0,$
$$
{\mathbb{E}}[p_x q_x] \leq {\mathbb{E}}[p_x] \cdot \underset{|\psi\rangle}{\mathsf{max}}|q_x|.
$$
Now, $q_x \leq 1$ and ${\mathbb{E}}[p_x] = 2^{-n}.$ Hence,
$$
{\mathbb{E}}[p_x q_x] \leq 2^{-n}.
$$
But is there a tighter bound?

Is $x$ taken in ${0,1}^n$ rather than ${0,1}$? That is, is $x\rangle$ simply any computational basis state? And do you choose $\left|\psi^\perp\right\rangle$ uniformly at random in the space orthogonal to $|\psi\rangle$? Otherwise you could definitely choose it so that $q_x$ is $0$.

I mean choosing $|\psi^{\perp}\rangle$ adversarially, such that $\mathbb{E}[p_x q_x]$ is the highest possible.

And when you say any choice of $x$ in ${0,1}$, do you mean that you want to maximize both $p_0q_0$ and $p_1q_1$, or any of the two will do?

Also, are you specifically interested in $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ only, or any computational basis state? It definitely changes the answer

Any basis state.

Or, formulated more clearly, is $x$ defined at the beginning of the protocol, or is it also adversarially chosen?

$x$ is defined in the beginning of the protocol.

You can prove a lower bound by exhibiting a good candidate for $\left|\psi^\perp\right\rangle$. Without loss of generality (by unitary invariance of the Haar measure), assume $x=0$. To any state $|\psi\rangle$, we associate:
$$\left|\psi^\perp\right\rangle=\frac{|0\rangle-\langle\psi|0\rangle\,|\psi\rangle}{\sqrt{1-|\langle0|\psi\rangle|^2}}$$
Intuitively, we take the state maximizing $p_0q_0$ (that is, $|0\rangle$) and then we orthonormalize it using Gram-Schmidt. We then have:
$$\begin{align}
    \mathbb{E}\left[p_0q_0\right] &= \mathbb{E}\left[|\langle0|\psi\rangle|^2\left(1-|\langle0|\psi\rangle|^2\right)\right]\\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[|\langle0|\psi\rangle|^2\right]-\mathbb{E}\left[|\langle0|\psi\rangle|^4\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{\left(2^n+1\right)2^{n-1}}
\end{align}$$
where the rightmost expectation has been computed using this answer.
In particular, assuming an adversarial setting, we have:
$$\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{\left(2^n+1\right)2^{n-1}}\leqslant\mathbb{E}\left[p_xq_x\right]\leqslant\frac{1}{2^n}$$
and thus, $\mathbb{E}\left[p_xq_x\right]\sim\frac{1}{2^n}$. We have even a bit stronger:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[p_xq_x\right]=\frac{1}{2^n}+O\left(\frac{1}{4^n}\right)\,.$$
In particular, there is no tighter bound, at least asymptotically speaking. Since we haven't proved that the $\left|\psi^\perp\right\rangle$ is optimal, maybe the lower-bound isn't tight and it's possible to have a better bound inbetween.
